# WebApp Unable to find type, How to compile source into target dir

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, gwt

Basically I'm having to 2 maven modules and one should start the application by inherit the client source from the other one (because the client includes the EntryPoint). 
Therefore I have 2 .gwt.xml files and to pom.xml files.

**gwt.gwt.xml**

```
<module>

    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <inherits name='org.fusesource.restygwt.RestyGWT' />
    <!--Specify the app entry point class. -->
    <entry-point class='com.myapp.admin.client.EntryPoint'/>    

    <source path='client'/>
    <source path='rest'/>
    <source path='consts'/>

</module>
```

**web.gwt.xml**

```
<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
<inherits name='com.myapp.admin.gwt' />
```

**POM client (gwt), packaging: jar**

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>attach-sources</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**POM web, packaging: war**

```
    <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
```

```
<!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>

</plugin>
```

plus it includes a dependency with the gwt-module `<classifier>sources</classifier>`. I can compile my application without errors but I cannot run it because

[ERROR] [web] - Unable to find type 'com.myapp.admin.client.EntryPoint'
    [ERROR] [web] - Hint: Check that the type name 'com.myapp.admin.client.EntryPoint' is really what you meant
    [ERROR] [web] - Hint: Check that your classpath includes all required source roots

Which is reasonable because there is no source in the directory. but why is there no source ?

thanks for any help.

Comment: How are you (trying to) run your project?

Comment: hi. I'm using eclipse. with run config -war "path to SNAPSHOT" com.myapp.admin.web (+port parameters and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using M2Eclipse with "resolve dependencies from the workspace", dependencies with a type different from `jar` (e.g. `java-source`) or a classifier all resolve to the `target/classes` of the Eclipse project, so you don't actually get the sources in your classpath.

AFAIK, Google Plugin for Eclipse takes the classpath from M2Eclipse, so you won't have the sources there. You need to edit the launch configuration to add the source directories (`src/main/java` and possibly others) of the projects you depend on to the classpath.